# How to implement Send mail and set meeting functionality using Microsoft Graph for Outlook?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, outlook

I am trying to implement a function that will send an email and set a meeting in Outlook using Microsoft Graph. I have been able to find some documentation on how to do each of these things separately, but not able to implement it.

Can anyone provide some guidance on how to do this? I would be grateful for any help that you can provide.

Thank you for your help!